# turn off javac warnings

Tags: java, warnings, compiler-warnings, javac

I have a problem:
I have to create a project for my studies. In the requirements I have a information that the whole project should be created in two files A.java and B.java.

The problem of project is complicated so I have created some helpfull class called e.x. MyClass. I put this class inside A.java - I cannot use another file.

Right now my A.java looks like that:

```
public class A {
 // some logic
}

final class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
    //some logic    
}
```

In the B.java I am using objects of MyClass and everything is working correctly.

The problem is with the second requirement of project.
The automatic compilation - after I will send my project to my university - starts the proccess like that:

```
javac –Xlint B.java A.java
```

Compilation is successfull but I have some warnings:

```
B.java:17: warning: auxiliary class MyClass in A.java should not be accessed from outside its own source file
    private MyClass variable;
```

The third requirement says that if you have any warnings or errors, your project will not be assessed. So I will fail my project if the warnings appears.

I know this is very stupid to store two classes in one file but this is unversity - here everything is stupid...

So - is there any solution to turn off warnings during compilation with javac?
I tried this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
final class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
```

but it doesn`t work - I still get the warnings...

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Your third requirement to not have any  warnings and errors isn't merely aesthetic. If the compiler is issuing a warning, your assessor will spot that to. Best to do as it suggests and clean up your code.

Comment: The warning is generated by class `B`, so the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation should be on `B`, not `MyClass`. But, using inner class so there aren't any warnings is much better than suppressing warnings, so go with [Andy Turner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330045/5221149).

Comment: @John the program will be compilated automatically and after that the console output is parsed. If parser will find any warning in output message, the project scores 0 points and it is not provided to my teacher :/ @Andy`s solution works perfect without any warnings in console :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `MyClass` inside `A`:

```
public class A {
 // some logic

  static final class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
      //some logic    
  }
}
```

and refer to it as `A.MyClass` from the other file.

Or import it (assuming `A` isn't in the default package), and refer to it as `MyClass`.

Or defining it in its own file would be the obvious option; but you say you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working with inner class.